# Simple Calculator Apps

Tags: c++

I wrote a simple calculator program. How can it be improved?

```
#include <iostream>

// get a double value from user
double getDoubleValue ()
{
    while (1)
    {
        std::cout << "Enter a double number: ";
        double d;
        std::cin >> d;

        if (std::cin.fail())
        {
            std::cin.clear();
            std::cin.ignore(32767, '\n');
            std::cout << "oops! you entered invalid number. Please try again.\n";
        }
        else
           {
            std::cin.ignore(32767, '\n');
            return d;
            }
    }
}

// get an operator from user
char getOperator()
{
    while (1)
    {
        std::cout << "Enter operator (+ , - , * , /): ";
        char ch;
        std::cin >> ch;

        std::cin.ignore(32767, '\n');

        if (ch == '+' || ch == '-' || ch == '*' || ch == '/')
            return ch;
        else
        std::cout << "oops. you entered invalid operator. please try again.\n";
    }
}

// show result of calculation
void printResult(double x, char ch, double y)
{
    switch (ch)
    {
        case '+':
            std::cout << x << ch << y << "= " << x+y;
            break;
        case '-':
            std::cout << x << ch << y << "= " << x-y;
            break;
        case '*':
            std::cout << x << ch << y << "= " << x*y;
            break;
        case '/':
            std::cout << x << ch << y << "= " << x/y;
            break;
        default :
            std::cout << "oops!";
            break;
    }
}

int main ()
{
    double x = getDoubleValue();
    double y = getDoubleValue();
    char ch = getOperator();

    printResult(x, ch, y);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `char ch = getDoubleValue()` should probably be `char ch = getOperator()` and `double y = getOperator()` should be `double y = getDoubleValue()`. Further more, for such errors, just using common sense seems like a better option ;)

Comment: holy.... i knew there is simple mistake . its because of tired mind. thanks

Comment: Please note that this website is for reviewing *working* code, not getting help with *broken* code. If your code doesn't work properly, then you are not ready to have it reviewed! The best tool for fixing broken code is a debugger.

Comment: Fixed obvious typo that OP had already acknowledged in comments. Code works as expected.

Comment: @LokiAstari the title is still awful. It should be a one-line summary of the code

Answer (score 5):

#### Don't write useless comments.

```
// get a double value from user
double getDoubleValue ()
```

Comments that echo the code are worse than no comments. AS over time they will fall out of sync with the code and thus cause maintenance issues. Do I fix the code to make it like the comment or do I fix the comment to make it like the code?

#### Yank common factors from the code

If something happens in both sides of an if statement (ie in both the true and false sub sections) then you can yank this code out and make it only happen once.

```
    if (std::cin.fail())
    {
        std::cin.ignore(32767, '\n');
    }
    else
    {
        std::cin.ignore(32767, '\n');
    }
```

#### Dont' use magic numbers

```
        std::cin.ignore(32767, '\n');
```

Why 32767? Check. See [How do I flush the cin buffer?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/257182/14065)

#### Stream and boolean

The stream object when used in a boolean context (an if or while statement) will convert itself to bool by calling the `good()` method. This makes reading and testing the read in a single statement easy.

```
    std::cin >> d;

    if (std::cin.fail())
    {
```

Can be replaced with:

```
    if (std::cin >> d)
    {
```

Note: Your code will break if you hit `EOF`. As `fail()` only checks if `badbit` or `failbit` has been set.

#### Do you really want to ignore garbage?

Currently your input function works as long as the prefix of the input matches what you want. If the rest of the line is garbage you ignore and throw it away.

```
Enter a double number: 145.56BLABLABLA
                       ^^^^^^                Good user input prefix
                             ^^^^^^^^^       Suffix of garbage ignored.
```

I would read a line from the input try and parse it and make sure there is no garbage on the end.

#### Re-Writting that loop we get:

```
    std::cout << "Enter a double number:\n";

    std::string line;
    while (std::getline(std::cin, line))
    {
        char   x;
        double d;

        std::stringstream lineStream(line);
        if ((lineStream >> d) && !(lineStream >> x))
        {
            // We successfully read a number followed by
            // nothing. ie it failed to read anything into x.
            return d;
        }

        // Some type of input error occurred reading the value
        std::cout << "oops! you entered invalid number. Please try again.\n";
    }
    // EOF failure. No more input to read.
    // Throw an exception here?
```

#### Seporation of Concerns

```
void printResult(double x, char ch, double y)
```

This code has two different functions. It performs an operation (as specified by `ch` then it prints out the value. You should separate these into different bits of code.

Your main looks like this:

```
double x  = getDoubleValue();
double y  = getDoubleValue();
char   ch = getOperator();
double r  = performOp(x, ch, y);

std::cout << x << " " << ch << " " << y << " = " << r << "\n";
```

#### Command Pattern

The command pattern is basically a way of saving functionality in an object. We can use this in combination with a map to make lookup of the op easy to do.

```
static std::map<char, std::function<double(double,double)>> actionMap
    = {
       {'+',[](double x, double y){return x+y;}},
       {'-',[](double x, double y){return x-y;}},
       {'*',[](double x, double y){return x*y;}},
       {'/',[](double x, double y){return x/y;}}
      };


 double x  = getDoubleValue();
 double y  = getDoubleValue();
 char   ch = getOperator();

 // Rather than a big switch statement.
 // Look up the appropriate command with `ch` from the map.
 double r = actionMap[ch](x,y);
```